Error while integrating Firebase with flutter app
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not create task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Cannot get property 'apiLevel' on null object

I am getting this error always

Please share your pubspec.yaml file and your build.gradle file.
